Points on a circle on a sphere, given the center and radius?
Assume a sphere of radius 1 and a circle on the surface of the sphere with a radius of angle θ. I want to calculate the points on the circumference of that circle. In plane geometry, you can calculate the points on the circumference of a circle at any angle with sine and cosine of that angle (multiplied by the radius and translated by the position of the center of the circle).
Is there an analogous method with a circle on a sphere? The center of the circle is in longitude and latitude, so angular rather than X,Y. I am aware that a circle on a sphere is defined by a plane through the sphere, and I can calculate that planar circle's radius given the above parameters. But taking those coordinates and converting them to the spherical (lat/long) coordinates is not clear to me. Or even if that is the simplest way to get the points on the surface of the sphere.
Any assistance here would be appreciated!

Do you know how to rotate in the $x$-$z$ plane, and then in the $x$-$y$ plane? A parametric form of a circle with angular radius $\theta$ at longitude and latitude $0$ on the unit sphere is given by $(\cos\theta, \sin\theta\cos t, \sin\theta\sin t)$ for $t \in [0, 2\pi]$. Then rotate the $x$ and $z$ coordinates by the desired latitude, then rotate the $x$ and $y$ coordinates by the desired longitude.

How can you have an angle be a radius?
